# CSS text marquee issues

Tags: html, css, css-animations, keyframe

A client has requested a marquee style scrolling text banner (yep)

Have had a go with using css animations but have a few quirks I can't iron out.

https://jsfiddle.net/u2f6qdya/

The issues are that the list elements are just 'knocked' out of the line and stack until the last one. The parent is positioned absolute so not sure why thats happening.

And the next issue is with the keyframes, I wish for the items to start right at the left, but start to come in again and scroll before they have finished animating off the right of the screen.

Code for the CSS:

```
.sliding-marquee {
    width: 100%;
    height: 44px;
    background-color: #000;
    opacity: 0.6;
    color: white;
    line-height: 44px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.sliding-marquee ul {
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    animation: marquee 20s linear infinite;
}

.sliding-marquee ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.sliding-marquee ul li i {
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.sliding-marquee ul li + li {
    margin-left: 40px;
}

@keyframes marquee {
    0%   { left: -100% }
    100% { left: 100% }
}
```

And markup:

```
    <div class="sliding-marquee">
        <ul>
            <li>TEXT 1</li>
            <li>LONGER TEXT 2</li>
            <li>EVEN LONGER TEXT 3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: You can add `white-space: nowrap` to your `ul` element to prevent the wrapping

Comment: @DirkPennings Didn't know that, looks better already.

Comment: Just an observation; it would make more sense for the text to scroll right-to-left in a western language. It is much harder to read the way you are scrolling.

Comment: clients request... :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a fiddle with pure CSS. Hope it will help.

https://jsfiddle.net/d946h29g/

The idea was to get the text width with Chrome Element Inspector.

```
@keyframes marquee {
    0% {
        left: -556px;
    }
    100% {
        left: 100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is literally what I did a few minutes ago and to the same affect. :)

Answer (score 0):

Issue #1: It isn't enough for you to just add `position: absolute;`, you still need a `width: 100%;`, or something like this, to `.sliding-marquee ul`. If you don't set the `width` to `100%`, the default will be `right: 0;` which means your `width` will goes from `100%` to `0%` while your animation is playing.

Modified version, fix issue#1: https://jsfiddle.net/wtm_w/0hp144r0/